# Is there a way to set TTL on a document within AWS Elasticsearch utilizing python library?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I  can't find anyway to setup TTL on a document within AWS Elasticsearch utilizing python elasticsearch library.

I looked at the code of the library itself, and there are no argument for it, and I yet to see any answers on google.

Comment: I do personally use OpenStack Horizon to upload documents to the cloud and the API supports TTL which is a difficult characteristic to find.

Comment: Looks like `_ttl` was deprecated. See [index lifecycle management (ILM)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is none, you can use the index management policy if you like, which will operate at the index level, not at the doc level. You have a bit of wriggle room though in that you can create a pattern `data-*` and have more than 1 index, `data-expiring-2020-...`, `data-keep-me`.

You can apply a template to the pattern `data-expiring-*` and set a transition to delete an index after lets say 20 days. If you roll over to a new index each day you will the oldest day being deleted at the end of the day once it is over 20 days.

This method is much more preferable because if you are deleting individual documents that could consume large amounts of your cluster's capacity, as opposed to deleting entire shards. Other NoSQL databases such as DynamoDB operate in a similar fashion, often what you can do is add another field to your `docs` such as `deletionDate` and add that to your query to filter out docs which are marked for deletion, but are still alive in your index as a deletion job has not yet cleaned them up. That is how the TTL in DynamoDB behaves as well, data is not deleted the moment the TTL expires it, but rather in batches to improve performance.